# How to Centre the titlePanel in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

In the Shiny package of R, how can you make the text in the titlePanel be centred on the top of the page?

[Here is an example of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGQ1Q.jpg)

The only code I've used for the titlePanel is:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("How to Centre Me??")
```

When I look at the documentation, the only variables the function takes is:

```
titlePanel(title, windowTitle = title)
```

So is it possible to centre the title?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use column() function.

like this:

```
fluidPage(
           column(3,offset = 4, titlePanel("How to Centre Me??")) 
           )
```

where 3 is column width and offset you can adjust according to your requirement.

Answer (score 37):

In case anyone is still in need of a simple solution:

```
titlePanel(
    h1("First level title", align = "center")
)
```

Answer (score 3):

With css:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      ".title {margin: auto; width: 200px}"
    )
  ),
  tags$div(class="title", titlePanel("Centered title"))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just give up on the titlePanel() which is usually centered over the sidebar and just do this:

```
    titlePanel(""),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        ),

        mainPanel(
           h1("This is my title now")
        )
```

Not elegant but oh-so-easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a navbarPage() you should you the `header=h1("title",align="center")` and footer('same syntax as header') arguments.